# Increasing number of tabs on an action

Tags: react-native

here I am trying to make a tab bar in which the number of tabs increases on pressing a button. The content of the tabs remains the same. What do I need
to do?

Comment: when you ask a question, you should give more details and your code, and what you try. for example, the tab bar which library you use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this. Although its in react not react-native but its almost same in both.

On the event increase the size of array and then
 ***{this.state.tabs.map((tab, idx) => (***  will replicate the component for you.

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Tabs from '@material-ui/core/Tabs';
import Tab from '@material-ui/core/Tab';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state={
      tabs:["Tab1"],
    }
  }

  replicate=()=>{
    let tabs = this.state.tabs;
    tabs.push("Tab2")
    this.setState({
      tabs
    })
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <>
       <button onClick={this.replicate}> Replicate</button>
       <Tabs
        value={"tabs"}
        indicatorColor="primary"
        textColor="primary"
        // onChange={handleChange}
        aria-label="disabled tabs example"
      >

        {/* // Here when the action is fired the array increases its size and this map replicate the tab */}

        {this.state.tabs.map((tab, idx) => (
          <Tab label="Active" />
        ))}
       </Tabs>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```